# Color change when exported to another software

Tags: materials, export

I am a new Blender user.

I have tried to save my project (a door with various parts) and importing it to Sweet Home 3D.

[image]

I had succeeded before, but then I worked on shadings. Since then, my doors appears on Sweet Home 3D with strange colors when exported there (just pink, nothing near what I worked on, not that I don't like pink, but I don't want my door to be pink).

[image]

On Sweet Home 3D, I can still identify different parts of my door (locker, inner casing, etc), so I think that my obj and mtl files are correctly linked (I exported as wavefront obj).

I don't understand. In Blender my door looks good with nice wood. How is that possible? Is there a specific option I should check on blender or while exporting?

Here is a picture of my nodetree.

[image]

I am working on Mac.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: You unfortunately don't show the nodetree of your material setup, but I can see in the screenshot that your _Principled BSDF_ has a _ColorRamp_ plugged in the _Base Color_. According to the [Blender Reference Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/node_shaders_info.html) only some parameters of the _Principled BSDF_ are supported and textures linked to it. Since there is no texture directly plugged into the color and maybe there are more things in the shader that are not compatible, this is most likely the reason why your door looks incorrect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,  @GordonBrinkmann! I have added a picture of my node tree in my post in case this make things clearer.

Comment: thanks for the link, Duarte, this will help!

Comment: Well, the screenshot of your nodetree only confirms what I already suspected in my comment. As I said and what is written in the manual, the export only supports the _Principled BSDF_ and textures linked to some of the parameters - and as specified in the manual, textures have to be image textures using a UV map. What you have there is a _ColorRamp_ as I could see earlier and a _Noise Texture_ (which is procedural and not an image texture), these things are simply not supported for OBJ.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! Now I know where to focus my attention and understand what all this means ! I will keep you posted.